# Using 'this' in constructor and other methods in Java - when is it OK to skip it?

Tags: java, this

I'm new to Java, so forgive me if it's a stupid question. I tried to find a clear answer on this forum but with no joy.

I know what **'this'** is. It know it refers to an actual instance and helps narrow the context when targeting a variable, but I found that it is possible to execute the code without any issues despite not using **'this'** phrase. Turns out it depends on how you name your parameters when you declare methods. As you can see below, code returns **'null'** if my parameter is named the same as the state I'm initialising/modifying.

This works only in the class where the variables are declared. You'd still have to use **'this'** in any sub-class, if it tried to access/modify a variable declared in its parent class.

Now, would this be considered incorrect and should it be avoided even though it seems to be working fine?

Thanks!

```
class Student {

  protected String name;
  protected int age;
  protected String course;

  public Student(String passName, int passAge, String course) {
    name = passName;
    age = passAge;
    course = course;   // here my parameter is named the same as the state and it will return 'null' unless we use 'this'

  }

  public void update(String newName, int newAge, String newCourse) {
    name = newName;
    age = newAge;
    course = newCourse;   // here I set the name of my parameter to be different and it works

  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\n Age: " + age + "\n Course: " + course + "\n");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Student s1 = new Student("John", 20, "Java 101");
    s1.display();

    s1.update("Johnny", 21, "Java 101");
    s1.display();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: John
 Age: 20
 Course: null

Name: Johnny
 Age: 21
 Course: Java 101
```

Comment: "Now, would **this** be considered incorrect and should it be avoided even though it seems to be working fine?" What do you mean by "this"?

Comment: "here my parameter is named the same as the state and it will return 'null'" It doesn't return anything: you're simply assigning the parameter to itself, and not doing anything to the field.

Comment: The answer to your question is to use "this";
After you understand the basics, maybe you can use Lombok for fast getters/setters/constructors/toString/EqualsAndHashCode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read [official documantation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) about "this" keyword.

> **Using this with a Field** The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor
> parameter.
>
> For example, the Point class was written like this
>
> ```
> public class Point {
>     public int x = 0;
>     public int y = 0;
>         
>     //constructor
>     public Point(int a, int b) {
>         x = a;
>         y = b;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> but it could have been written like this:
>
> ```
> public class Point {
>     public int x = 0;
>     public int y = 0;
>         
>     //constructor
>     public Point(int x, int y) {
>         this.x = x;
>         this.y = y;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Each argument to the constructor shadows one of the object's fields —
> inside the constructor x is a local copy of the constructor's first
> argument. To refer to the Point field x, the constructor must use
> this.x.

About you question:

> Now, would this be considered incorrect and should it be avoided even
> though it seems to be working fine?

It is depends for code style do yoy have in your projects or teams. Technically, both ways are possible and correct, using `name = newName` is shorter, and using `this.name = name` is more safe to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! Your very last paragraph answered my question.

Comment: Hi! If this post answered for your question, could you accept it, please (just to help other how read this topic in the future)? Or you can accept any other answer, if you think it more suitable for you.

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, if you give an instance variable the same name as a constructor argument, the assignment such as

```
course = course;
```

doesn't initialize the instance variable, since the constructor's argument `course`, which is a local variable, hides the instance variable of the same name. You are assigning the local variable to itself.

Hence the instance variable remains `null`.

You'll have to write

```
this.course = course;
```

in order for the assignment to work.

If, on the other hand, the name of the instance variable is different from the constructor argument's name, you can assign the constructor's argument to the instance variable without using the `this` prefix.

both

```
course = newCourse;
```

and

```
this.course = newCourse;
```

would work fine.

Note that using the `this` prefix even when it's not mandatory has an advantage of spotting bugs.

For example, if you wrote by mistake

```
newCourse = course;
```

the compiler will not complain, but your `course` instance variable won't be initialized.

On the other hand, if you wrote by mistake

```
this.newCourse = course;
```

the compiler will give a compilation error, since `newCourse` is not an instance variable.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your comment. I know why ```course = course``` doesn't work, and why `this` is required in this particular case. My main query was if skipping 'this' is fine, providing you name your characters differently. That's a great point about bug finding if your variables are in reverse order. From now on 'this' it is, then! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's the variable name that counts. Java always uses the variable in the closest scope available, so if you use a parameter with the same name, it will use the parameter. To avoid that, you need to qualify the field with `this`.
Here (irrelevant code removed):

```
  public Student(String course) {
    course = course;
  }
```

you assign the value of `course` to the parameter `course`, so the field `course` remains unchanged. For instance, if you do this:

```
  public Student(final String course) {
    course = course;
  }
```

it will not compile because the `final` keyword means you're not allowed to assign a new value to the variable (in this case, parameter `course`).

So you need to use `this` to assign to the field.

```
  public Student(final String course) {
    this.course = course;
  }
```

It's never "incorrect" to use `this`, but you might consider it good practice to not name parameters the same as fields anyway (and there are warnings to activate in IDEs if you do, to prevent exactly that).

Comment: Why would it be a good practice to not name parameters the same as fields; but that's how AllArgsConstructor and setters work